# Console Calculator in c# with a chain of calculations

Tags: c#, loops, console, calculator, chain

I need some help with my code.
Here is how the task looks like:

Develop a console program "Calculator", which reads arithmetic operators in loop iteration, 
which user inputs  ("+", "-", "*", "/") and its operands (real numbers), and then calculates, 
bringing to Screen result of the operation, which is then used in the next operation as the
first operand (as a result, program will be something like a chain of successive calculations).
The program must correctly handle errors (division by zero, entering the number instead of 
arithmetic operators, etc.) and notify the user, without interrupting the work.

This is what I've got so far:

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите число x");
            double x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
      while (true)
         {   Console.WriteLine("Введите число y");
            double y = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("// Выберите операцию //");
            Console.WriteLine("+ - сложение");
            Console.WriteLine("- - вычитание");
            Console.WriteLine("* - умножение");
            Console.WriteLine("/ - деление");
            string z = Console.ReadLine();
                switch (z)
                {
                    case "+":
                        Console.WriteLine("// Результат //");
                        Console.WriteLine(x + y);
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        Console.WriteLine("// Результат //");
                        Console.WriteLine(x - y);
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        Console.WriteLine("// Результат //");
                        Console.WriteLine(x * y);
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        if (y == 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Не дели на 0");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("// Результат //");
                            Console.WriteLine(x / y);
                        }
                        break;
                }
```

}

I've successfully added division by zero restriction, but that's about all.
I don't know, how to make this "chain of calculations". Of course, I understand that I must use loop, but can't come up with anyting. What I've got not is - two numbers are getting operated and that's all, program stops. I tried adding

```
do
  {
    //main program body
    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to continue");
    keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
  }
while (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter);
```

but that only makes the program start from the beginning. I need the result of the first operation to become the first operand and so on. Then user must type something for this program to end.

Sorry for my English, and sorry for my poor c# knowledge, unfortunately, I'm a beginner.
Hope to hear soon, thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was downvoted.  The problem is clear, the OP showed the code written so far and is asking for help.  While this might be a homework question, I didn't know we automatically downvoted homework questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly printing the result of the calculation, store the result into the `x` variable, print it out and then ask the user to enter the next `y`.  This way, x will contain the result of the previous calculation, allowing you to "chain" it to the next one.  You only ask for x the first time and ask for y each time the loop repeats.

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите число x");
double x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Введите число y");
    double y = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("// Выберите операцию //");
    Console.WriteLine("+ - сложение");
    Console.WriteLine("- - вычитание");
    Console.WriteLine("* - умножение");
    Console.WriteLine("/ - деление");
    string z = Console.ReadLine();

    switch (z)
    {
       case "+":
           Console.WriteLine("// Результат //");
           x = (x + y);  //Store the result in x
           Console.WriteLine(x);
           break;
       case "-":
           Console.WriteLine("// Результат //");
           x = (x - y);  //Store the result in x
           Console.WriteLine(x);
           break;
       case "*":
           Console.WriteLine("// Результат //");
           x = (x * y);  //Store the result in x
           Console.WriteLine(x);
           break;
       case "/":
           if (y == 0)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Не дели на 0");
           }
           else
           {
               Console.WriteLine("// Результат //");
               x = (x / y);
               Console.WriteLine(x);
           }
           break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir!
I've got the last question, how do I restrict entering a number instead of arithmetic operators (y) and display a message?

Comment: To make sure that `y` contains a valid double, use the `Double.TryParse` method instead of `Convert.ToDouble`.  `TryParse` will return an true or false that tells you if the conversion succeeded.  I like to put these input routines in another method for easy reuse.

Comment: UPD. Oh no, I did as you wrote, but the problem is, it calculates wrong.
For example, I input X as 11, Y as 22, use the addition, the result is 33. Then it asks me to input Y again, I write 20, but now I use subtration. The result is -9, but it should be 13.
So, you see, it uses the first X as the operand, but it must use the result of the operation.

Comment: It works for me when I copy the code above into LinqPad.  I get 13, as expected.  Double check your code for typos or use the debugger to step through the code line by line and examine the variable values.  Or edit your code and copy your updated code for more help.

Comment: Gosh, I understood it, I can't read. Thank you for you help, sir.

Comment: Hello again, sir. I have another question, how do I do this?
When I press "=", it must repeat last operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
        while(true){
        Console.WriteLine("Введите число x");
        double x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Введите число y");
        double y = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("// Выберите операцию //");
        Console.WriteLine("+ - сложение");
        Console.WriteLine("- - вычитание");
        Console.WriteLine("* - умножение");
        Console.WriteLine("/ - деление");
        string z = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (z)
            {
                case "+":
                    Console.WriteLine("// Результат //");
                    Console.WriteLine(x + y);
                    break;
                case "-":
                    Console.WriteLine("// Результат //");
                    Console.WriteLine(x - y);
                    break;
                case "*":
                    Console.WriteLine("// Результат //");
                    Console.WriteLine(x * y);
                    break;
                case "/":
                    if (y == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Не дели на 0");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("// Результат //");
                        Console.WriteLine(x / y);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to exit ?! Y:N?");
            char Terminat= Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
           if(Terminat=='Y'||Terminat=='y'){
             break;
              }

}
```

Comment: 1) It tells me that "||" can't be used with char and bool
2) It still doesn't use the result of first operation as the first operand of the next operation. (I hope you understood me)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer(implemented in C#) to those looking for calculator based on grammar based parsing. I have adapted this from Stroustrup's "Programming principles and practice using C++"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CalculatorApplication
{
    class Calculator
    {
        string input;
        char[] szArr;
        int length ;
        int current = -1;
        char ch;
        public Calculator(String input)
        {
            this.input = input;
            szArr = input.ToCharArray();
           length = szArr.Length;
        }
        char nextToken()
        {
            ++current;
            if(current==length) return 'p';
            return szArr[current];
        }
        public double expression()
        {
            double d = term();
            while(true){
            switch (ch)
            {
                case '+':
                    d+= term();
                    break;
                case  '-':
                    d -= term();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
            if (ch == 'p') break;
        }
            return d;

        }


        public double term()
        {
            double d = primary();
            switch (ch)
            {
                case '*':
                    d *= primary();
                    break;
                case '/':
                     d /= primary();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
            return d;
        }
        public double primary()
        {
            string str = "";
            double value = 0.0;
            while (true)
            {

                ch = nextToken();
                if (isDigit(ch))
                {
                    str += ch;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            value = double.Parse(str);
            return value;

        }

        bool isDigit(char ch)
        {
            return ch == '0' || ch == '1' || ch == '2' || ch == '3' || ch == '4' || ch == '5' || ch == '6' || ch == '7' || ch == '8' || ch == '9';
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter expression");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(new Calculator(input).expression());          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your calculator has bugs such getting stuck in an endless while loop under certain conditions. In my answer I used a similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

I made a primitive calculator that can evaluate complex math expressions with brackets ( ) and operator precedence using these operators: + - * / % and ^.

https://github.com/henon/PrimitiveCalculator

This is what it can do (interactive console output):

```
calc> 1/2*2
 = 1
calc> 2^1+1
 = 3
calc> 7777777777777+8888888888888
 = 16666666666665
calc> 1+2+3+4+5+7+8
 = 30
calc> 1+2*3
 = 7
calc> 1+2*3-1
 = 6
calc> (1+2)*(3-1)
 = 6
calc> (1+2)*(3-2)
 = 3
calc> 1+2*3-2
 = 5
calc> (1+2)*3
 = 9
calc> 44%10
 = 4
calc>  1+ 2 * 7
 = 15
calc> 10/3
 = 3.3333333333333335
calc> 0.3*9
 = 2.6999999999999997
calc> -0.22345 + -1.1
 = -1.32345
```